# Effcient way to store and display in a PHP web application

Tags: php, web-applications, web, content-management-system

I am developing a PHP web application. Looking for the efficient way of storing user uploaded images and display it on the web application. Please let me know your suggestions.

Expected number of images is 1 million.

Comment: There are several ways. For example do you want to store it i the database or simply on the filesystem?

Comment: Store them in the filesystem so you can deal faster with preview/thumbnail caching, and leave db entries as well to manage relationship with users.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to use a combination of filesystem storage and database storage. Create a table that will contain your metadata about the image (user ID of uploader, etc) and include a field for the image's URL.

When someone uploads an image, move the file to a directory that is accessible from the web, and then store a record in the table you created which contains all the relevant data about the uploaded file, including the URL for the image. This way you can query the database for information about the image but you don't have to store the file's contents in the database.

Comment: How do you handle this if you need to load balance among multiple web servers?

Comment: you would have all the web servers connect to a common database server. If you needed to have multiple database servers, there are different ways to do this per database vendor but for MySQL you would probably set up a single master database for writing to and multiple replicated slaves for reading from. The URL for the image would point to a file server (amazon AWS is good for this) which you would upload to.

Comment: The common database server was obvious, the part about using a service like AWS for the image files was the point I didn't think of.

Comment: Which one is better between going for AWS pricing or setting up own server?

Comment: @sudhakar this is a question you can only answer yourself - if you make estimates of how much it'd cost to run your own server vs how much you'd expect to pay to amazon in fees, you can see which would be better for you. In general though, I expect AWS would be cheaper and easier to manage.